# Calculate Sample Variance in window 2 sec before to current sec through 3 seconds after current second using rollapply

Tags: r

This is what am trying to do:

| Time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 12 |
| 00:01 | 6 |
| 00:02 | 8 |
| 00:03 | 12 |
| 00:04 | 11 |
| 00:05 | 6 |
| 00:06 | 13 |
| 00:07 | 12 |
| 00:08 | 12 |

and i want sample variance and result like:

| Time | value | samp_vars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 12 | NA |
| 00:01 | 6 | NA |
| 00:02 | 8 | 24.1666 |
| 00:03 | 12 | 12.8 |
| 00:04 | 11 | 6.8 |
| 00:05 | 6 | 3.0667 |
| 00:06 | 13 | 3.7 |
| 00:07 | 12 | 3.5833 |
| 00:08 | 12 | 0.333 |

I tried doing this:
`df$samp_vars <- rollapply(df$value, list(c(-2,0,3)), var, fill = NA)`

but my variance sample was not correct. I am not an expert in R so i will appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: what values are you expecting? I make the variance at 00:02 to be 8.166 - not 24.166

Comment: I calculated this sample variance using Excel and wanted to replicate it in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the expected values to be `NA, NA, 8.166, 9.466, 7.466, 6.400, NA, NA, NA` — not as you have in the question. For example, at `00:02`

```
var(c(12,6,8,12,11,6))
```

To get those values, simply alter your existing code to use a sequence of the right integers using `:` — at the moment you are getting the variance at the current row, the row two steps back and the row three steps forward, not all in between.

```
zoo::rollapply(data$value, list(-2:3), var, fill = NA)
```

The `-2:3` is making a vector of the integers `c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)` for you.